# Subversion merge to branch is incomplete - broken mergeinfo?

Tags: svn

The merging of one our branches is broken and I would welcome some help to fix it please.

One of our developers merged to the branch from trunk, but failed to commit the changes to the top of the branch so the mergeinfo was lost. He also cherry-picked the files, so it was a bit of a mess.  I made some subsequent commits to try to fix this, but I ended up reverting my commits and the erroneous merge. So the branch should now be as it was prior to that merge.

Now, when I attempt to merge from the trunk to that branch, I don’t get all the expected changes from the trunk.  The branch’s mergeinfo is:

```
<various branches>
trunk:7268-8029

Head revision is r8063.
```

What I see is that the changes that are not merged are all in one particular folder. Other folders are merged. But I have checked in the branch that that folder and its subfolders do not have mergeinfo.

I am baffled. Where should I look to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve fixed it. I was mistaken, a mergeinfo property was set on the offending, lower-level folder. Deleting that property resulted in a complete merge.